# How can I access remote DB over SSL?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, ssh

```
[AP Server] --> [DB Server] (over SSL)
```

I need to access to remote DB Server over SSL but I can't connect to DB server when I execute mysql command. Any help will be appreciated.

What I did:

1. Created .pem files.

   ```
   /tmp/ca-cert.pem
   /tmp/server-cert.pem
   /tmp/server-no-password-key.pem
   ```
2. Changed my.cnf

   ```
   [mysqld]
   ssl-ca=/tmp/ca-cert.pem
   ssl-cert=/tmp/server-cert.pem
   ssl-key=/tmp/server-no-password-key.pem
   ```
3. Restart mysql and check settings

   ```
   $mysql -u user1 -p --ssl-ca=/tmp/ca-cert.pem

   mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
   +---------------+---------------------------------+
   | Variable_name | Value                           |
   +---------------+---------------------------------+
   | have_openssl  | YES                             |
   | have_ssl      | YES                             |
   | ssl_ca        | /tmp/ca-cert.pem                |
   | ssl_capath    |                                 |
   | ssl_cert      | /tmp/server-cert.pem            |
   | ssl_cipher    |                                 |
   | ssl_crl       |                                 |
   | ssl_crlpath   |                                 |
   | ssl_key       | /tmp/server-no-password-key.pem |
   +---------------+---------------------------------+

   mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
   +---------------+--------------------+
   | Variable_name | Value              |
   +---------------+--------------------+
   | Ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA |
   +---------------+--------------------+
   ```
4. SSH access from AP Server to DB server-key

   ```
   ssh dbserver // pubkey login is ok.
   ```
5. Tried mysql access from AP Server to DB Server

   ```
   $ mysql -u user1 -p -h dbserver --ssl-ca=/tmp/ca-cert.pem
   Enter password: 
   ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbserver' (110)
   ```

FYI:

DB Server does not allow ssh password authentication. Only pubkey login is allowed

Thanks

---

Update

My first goal is running this PHP script from AP Server. This script worked in DB Server.

```
<?php

$dbh   = mysqli_init();

$isSSL = mysqli_ssl_set(
    $dbh,
    '/tmp/server-no-password-key.pem',
    '/tmp/server-cert.pem',
    '/tmp/ca-cert.pem',
    null,
    null
);
$isConnected = mysqli_real_connect(
    $dbh,
    'dbserver',
    'user1',
    'user1-pass',
    'dbname1',
    3306,
    null,
    MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL
);
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

---

Update2

I think Grants are no problem.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR user1;
------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*******************' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Regarding firewall, port 3306 is closed. I guess I don't need to open when I use SSL. In fact, sequel pro(sql client application) can connect to the DB even 3306 is closing. SSH private key setting is likely the cause...

---

Update3

Some websites show that SSH port forwarding. That is much easier... creating .pem files and setting that is just waste of my time....? I will check it.

---

Update4

It worked!

```
ssh user1@dbserver -p 22 -g -N -f -L 12345:localhost:3306
mysql -uuser1 -p -h 127.0.0.1 –port=12345
```

What still I'm not sure is .pem setting is necessary or not. When I remove mysqli_ssl_set, I can see raw data by tcpdump. I think ssh forwarding encrypt the data throughout public network... It does not make sense..

```
sudo tcpdump -nxX -s 2000 port 3306 -ilo
```

Comment: is there still a question or you figured out everything yourself? If so, please post the answer as an answer and not an Edit.

Comment: *Regarding firewall, port 3306 is closed. I guess I don't need to open when I use SSL.* Well, yes, you do.  The entire question here seems flip flop between *SSL* and *SSH*, which are two unrelated things.